# Passing different variable values to event handlers in a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, click, apply

Guys I'm only a beginner and I'm not entirely sure how to from the question I have. 
I'm working on a little plugging which restyles all the HTML  *inputs*. The issue I have is when it comes to multiple instances of  *drop downs per page*, no matter on which <\select> I click only the very last <\select> reacts (shows drop down menu).

```
$(function () { // Document ready 
    test(document.getElementsByClassName("js_select"));
});


function test(selects) {
    var i = 0
    var l = selects.length;

    for (i; i < l; i++) {
        var thisSelect = selects[i];
        var xVariable = i * 10;

        $(thisSelect).click(function () {
            onDivClick.apply(this, [xVariable]);
        });
    }
    function onDivClick(variable) {
        console.log(variable);
    }
}
```

So here, I've made a little example to replicate my code and show what's going on. I do understand that with every iteration of the loop, the value of *"xVariable"* changes, and click event for every "selects" picks up only the very last value of *"xVariable"*.

How can a tweak this so that when I click on the first , I get "0" in console, the next select prints "10", and so on...?

Is there a way to get around this without object notation?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You could just iterate through the selects using `each` and just the bind the `click` event like so:

```js
(function () {
 $(".js_select").each(function(idx) {
   $(this).on("click", function() {
     console.log(idx * 10);
    });
  });
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="" id="" class="js_select">
  <option value="">-- Select a Value --</option>
  <option value="0">test</option>
</select>
<br>
<select name="" id="" class="js_select">
  <option value="">-- Select a Value --</option>
  <option value="0">test</option>
</select>
<br>
<select name="" id="" class="js_select">
  <option value="">-- Select a Value --</option>
  <option value="0">test</option>
</select>
```

I've added a sample list of selects to make it easier to understand how it all works.

Answer (score 0):

Or without the big bad ugly jQuery

```js
// You could also use querySelectorAll
let selects = document.getElementsByClassName('js_select');

// Make sure there are selects
if(selects) {
  for(let i = 0; i < selects.length; i++) {
    let select = selects[i];
    
    select.addEventListener('click', function() {
      console.log(i * 10);
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<select class="js_select">
  <option value="">-- Select a Value --</option>
  <option value="0">test</option>
</select>
<br>
<select class="js_select">
  <option value="">-- Select a Value --</option>
  <option value="0">test</option>
</select>
<br>
<select class="js_select">
  <option value="">-- Select a Value --</option>
  <option value="0">test</option>
</select>
```